# is it ok to store large string on the sting.xml

Tags: android

I am creating a hymn app and this contain like 500 hymns. So is it ok to store these 500 hymn lyric in string.xml or should I store in a database because I don't want my app to take too much  memory space. Thank you

Comment: Did you try it? If so, what happened?

Comment: I'm still building it

Comment: both xml and database are file. there is no difference. but if your data hasnt structure dont use database

Comment: the memory consumption is not related to either approach

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean memory space I mean the space of a device

Comment: you should use a database if you have relations between data.

Comment: 500 little bits of text is not going to be a lot of data. Today even 500 novels in pure text form would not be a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would better if you put them in Json file and during the first install display to the user a splash screen with a loading animatin ,during the loading you can parse the json file and save it in the realm database example of the Json file :

```
    [
  {
    "Hymn1": {
      "title": "title 1",
      "singer": "singer1",
      "Lyrics": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    }
  },
  {
    "Hymn2": {
      "title": "title 2",
      "singer": "singer2",
      "Lyrics": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    }
  }
]
```

you can check this documentation of realm:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json

Answer (score 0):

You can store all information in a .json file and place that file in your app.
You will notice that the file will not weigh much.